# Spark.ml on Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

Is it possible to use Spark libraries such as Spark.ml within a Beam pipeline?
From my understanding, you will write your pipeline in “beam syntax” and let Beam
execute it on spark using spark as a runner.
Hence, I don’t see how you could use spark.ml within beam.

But maybe I get something wrong here?
Did someone already try to use it, if not, do other ML libraries exist for native usage in Beam (except from Tensorflow Transform)?

Many Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: By "Did someone already try to use it, if not, do other ML libraries exist for native usage in Beam (except from Tensorflow Transform)?" it looks like you have not looked around. Please look around carefully before asking a question. Most of the times, the answer will be found quicker than you think.

Comment: Hey Jbuchel, thanks for you comment. I actually did look around for examples or similar projects, but as stated, I wasn't able to find something. So, I would say I did my basic research though I can't rule out that someone in the community did it already but haven't wrote/blogged/published about it. Hence, I still would be interesting, if it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) unifies stream and batch data processing. Its portable, meaning SDKs can be written in any language and it can be executed in any data processing frameworks with enough capabilities(see: [runners](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/)). ML in not its main concern. So [its programming model](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) does not define any unified API to work with ML.

But id does not mean that you cannot use it with ML libraries to preprocess data needed to your ML model for training or inference. It is well suited to do it for you. Beam comes with set of [build IOs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/). Which may help you to get data from many sources.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this great answer!
I knew, that Apache Beam is usable with different runners and used for big data stream and batch processing, however, such as spark is also a big data processing framework it has spark.ml where machine learning algorithms and functionality is already written in spark. 
Can I use spark.ml in beam when I choose spark as runner? 
Is there a similar project for beam?

Comment: Hey, short answer. No, you cannot use Spark ML in Beam. Spark Ml is ML library build on tom of Spark data processing. Beam does data processing not ML.

Comment: Thanks plastique for your answer!